# Martingale Proofs

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I havent been able to find an analogous question and our textbook is lacking in good examples, so I could use a little help with this rather straight forward martingale problem:

Let X=(Xn) be a sequence of independent random variables on (omega,ℙ,F) where ℙ(Xn=1) = p and ℙ(Xn=-1) = q := 1-p
Set Yn = ΣXi for i to n
Define Mn = (e^(aYn))(pe^a + qe^-a)^-n for a>0
Show that Mn is a Fn-martingale

So I think I understand the idea of the martingale and the objective of the proof. A martingale is a process where ExpectedValue(Mn+1) = Mn. So to prove something is a martingale we can prove that or equivalently that ExpectedValue(Mn+1) - ExpectedValue (Mn) = 0.

I started by saying that we know: 
Mn+1 = Mn(e^(aYn+1))(pe^a + qe^-a)^(-n+1)
From there I take the expectation of each side:
ExpectedValue(Mn+1|Fn) = ExpectedValue(Mn(e^(aYn+1))(pe^a + qe^-a)^(-n+1))
We can bring the Mn out because ExpectedValue(Mn) = Mn:
= Mn(ExpectedValue((e^(aYn+1))(pe^a + qe^-a)^(-n+1)))

But I get stuck as this point and I am not sure what the next step is (or if I went awry earlier). It seems like everything left in the expected value should but the exponential seems problematic in that respect. Perhaps I am going about it wrong?

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prove
$$ E(M_n | \mathcal F_{n-1}) = M_{n-1} $$
where $\mathcal F_n$ is the minimal sigma algebra with respect to which $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are measurable.

Now $M_n = e^{aY_n}(pe^a + qe^{-a})^{-n}$.  Let's compute:
$$ E(M_n | \mathcal F_{n-1}) = p \cdot e^{a(Y_{n-1} + 1)}(pe^a + qe^{-a})^{-n} + q \cdot e^{a(Y_{n-1} - 1)}(pe^a + qe^{-a})^{-n}) ,$$
since $Y_{n-1}$ is $\mathcal F_{n-1}$ measurable.  After this it is just algebra.

Comment: Ah yes, this is it. My teacher's textbook is riddled with errors, which led me a bit astray. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Not too long ago, there was a similar problem related to Martingale theory: [Exercise 1.3.2 of Norris, "Markov Chains"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573675/exercise-1-3-2-of-norris-markov-chains/573695#573695)
Maybe that helps..

Comment: hmm that's perhaps generally informative, but I dont think that helps me. I think my problems are more in the exponential part the expected value and making sure that I am not misunderstanding/misapplying the martingale definition. Thanks though!

Comment: I think in my link there is a link to a Wikipedia page that is more informative about Martingale