# Matrices whose elements are matrices

Tags: matrices

I've worked with matrices whose elements are objects in a field, such that real numbers, complex numbers, inclusive functions in space of functions, but... Today I was talking to a friend and he asked me about something he saw in his PhD in informatic science that was about "matrices with matrices in their entries" and I know that we can make an arrange of the blocks of the matrices in the entries to form a matrix in a $nxn$ space, for some $n$... but... what use or there is any example of how is useful a matrix with this characteristic?

Comment: You can get matrices where elements belong to a ring, and the matrices over any ring also form a ring.

Comment: and there is a practical use or just a perfect way to enjoy the perfect matrix theory we have develope?

Comment: Based on the context you have provided, I wonder if you are really talking about matrices with matrix entries, or arrays in some some programming language with array entries?  Are these really being treated like matrices? or is this just a data storage convention?  or are these really just block matrices?

Comment: Or do you consider representations of [planar algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_algebra) as an application of matrices with matrix entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of applications of matrices consisting of "sub" matrices (or as you call "block" matrices). One nice example that comes to mind is the use of block matrices in Absorbing Markov processes. In such a matrix, there are typically four "block" matrices: An Identity matrix, a Zero matrix, a matrix indicating the "flow" from the non absorbing states to the absorbing states and a matrix indicating the flow between non absorbing states. For the future (time going to infinity), the matrix indicating the flow from non absorbing to absorbing is very much of interest as that gives information about probabilities ending up in some absorbing state depending on where you are to begin with. This block matrix is also important for expectation. In order to arrive at such a result, some basic matrix algebra involving block matrices is needed and thus block matrices become important. I will spare you the algebra, but here is an example: [Exercise 1.3.2 of Norris, "Markov Chains"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573675/exercise-1-3-2-of-norris-markov-chains)

Answer (score 4):

As an example, suppose $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ and $B_1,\ldots, B_m$ are vector spaces. For any linear transformation $f:\bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_i\to\bigoplus_{j=1}^m B_j$ define $f_{ji}=\pi_j\circ f\circ\iota_i$, where $\pi_j:\bigoplus_{j=1}^m B_j\to B_j$ is the canonical projection and $\iota_i:A_i\to\bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_i$ is the canonical injection. Then if we fix bases of all the $A_i$'s and $B_j$'s, the transformation $f$ is uniquely represented by an $m\times n$ matrix whose $(j,i)$-th entry is the matrix representing $f_{ji}$.

Comment: I got "warned" by the moderation team for answering this presumably Problem Stated Question, which is deemed inappropriate for this site. Since you also answered, did you also get such a private message from the moderation team?

Comment: @imranfat I did not. Maybe I have something to look forward to in life?

Comment: @blargoner As a user of lower reputation, you may read [Closed questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Here, we cover questions which aren't a good fit for the site, and some users contribute to the site by closing such questions until they are clarified. Some users have felt that this question be closed. For example, from a background of informatic science, it's not clear where vector spaces come in immediately, nor Markov chains. Clarifications have also been asked for in the comments. Users of higher reputation should be informed and refrain from attempts.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon That's an interesting observation. But if the OP is satisfied with the answer, I don't see the issue. On the other hand, I don't make the rules either so who am I to contest? Apparently the moderation team considers me with my less than 10K a "higher reputation contributor" even though most of the time I am not even sure what I am talking about...:) Well, at least I feel some honor in here!

Comment: @imranfat Thanks for your response : I spoke to a moderator about this, and "extremely roughly" speaking, $3$K is a threshold that would say : "informed about site policies and rules" : it's when the close/reopen privilege opens up , and one needs to be fairly informed to use this privilege. Now, the OP is satisfied with the answer, but as I mentioned, it's not clear how this links to "informatics theory" : the problem is, a talk with a friend , especially one dropping such a vague term , can lack clarity, as the link with IT shows. The OP is satisfied, but that's because you managed to...

Comment: ... provide one of many possible interpretations that could have suited them. For example, the application of encoding vector spaces is there as well, codes use block matrices often. Then there's sparse matrices : since sparse matrices can be interpreted as blocks of smaller sparse matrices, recursive algorithms show up due to interpretation. Then there's Schur's decomposition for certain positive definite symmetric matrices. Quite which of these, @imranfat is best qualified is a guess, but I guess this is a question that isn't bad or wrong, just unclear and nothing more.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Interesting information. But I can't help it but thinking it is kind of looking for a needle in a haystack, BUT, it is how it is...thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: @imranfat I also apologize for calling you out as merely a high-rep user in the comment to blargoner above : I would have referenced you but I'm not able to reference two users in a comment and I could leave only one comment, hence my indecision. I wish you a good day, I hope I was able to explain myself a little more. I just think that sometimes we do have disagreements over what's unclear and what's not, and it's better to be on the safer side if the question is unclear : leaving a comment and saying "is this kind of what you are looking for?" is super-helpful, for example.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Frankly, this all seems to me like much ado about nothing. The original question seemed fairly straightforward to me: it's asking about matrices whose elements are matrices. Who cares that it was inspired by a discussion with someone from informatics science? It seems like there's a lot of nitpicking going on in the comments. Anyway, I love getting notified on every response to this thread, and I look forward to probably losing points gained trying to help someone.

Comment: @blargoner "Who cares ... informatics science" it is mentioned in the post, so even though it's not important, it's still worth noting as that's what the friend most likely may have alluded to if the conversation had continued. The purpose of that context was to allow answers to allude to it. You did, but without realizing it : I talked about encoding information in informatics using vector spaces. I am not calling your work by any means as a cardinal sin, but I'm just outlining the fact that there are differences of opinion regarding whether this question is suitable or not, and it was...

Comment: ... important that you be aware of this, as someone who was  notified of the discussion. Besides, if you want to be participating in a discussion regarding this question and its closure, you can visit the CURED chatroom which is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured), you have enough reputation to comment and ask about this particular question. In particular, you can try to defend the lack of clarity I spoke about. Now whether the site rules are much ado about nothing : it's fair to say I disagree here, and can defend this.